# Automobile accident data in the US

Tags: data-request, usa, medical, transportation, traffic

A friend's question:

> Are there data about automobile accidents over the course of a year with daily increments and preferably with a large variety of filters like city, highway, etc?

Comment: and italian automobile accident?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**California Polytechnic State University** has a downloaded dataset on fatal accidents on the national highway system for the year 2007:

https://wiki.csc.calpoly.edu/datasets/wiki/HighwayAccidents

**Data.Gov** has a number of datasets on accident data by state:
https://explore.data.gov/catalog/raw?tags=crash

**The NHTSA** has summary statistics for 2012 on a state by state basis here:
http://www-nrd.nhtsa.dot.gov/departments/nrd-30/ncsa/STSI/USA%20WEB%20REPORT.HTM

**The Insurance Institute for Highway Safety** has accident/safety ratings per make/model/year, but you will have to scrap it off their site:
http://www.iihs.org/iihs/ratings

Some of the city level open data portals also publish traffic accident datasets:

**Denver**: http://data.opencolorado.org/dataset/city-and-county-of-denver-traffic-accidents
**Seattle**: https://data.seattle.gov/Public-Safety/Traffic-Accidents/7ayk-pspk

**The UK data.gov** publishes accident/road safety datasets from 1979 to present here:
http://data.gov.uk/dataset/road-accidents-safety-data

*I put together an online catalog of sites covering traffic surveys and traffic accidents: http://www.opengeocode.org/opendata/traffic.php*

**A list of links from [albert](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/users/90/albert)**,
NCSA Publications & Data Requests http://www-nrd.nhtsa.dot.gov/Cats/index.aspx
 you probably want this guy:
http://www-nrd.nhtsa.dot.gov/Cats/listpublications.aspx?Id=F&ShowBy=DocType

super in-depth stats
http://www-fars.nhtsa.dot.gov/Main/index.aspx

crash stats archive
http://ai.fmcsa.dot.gov/CarrierResearchResults/Archives.asp?p=23

stats and facts
http://www.fmcsa.dot.gov/facts-research/art-stats-facts.htm

nhtsa data
http://www.nhtsa.gov/NCSA

federal trans safety somtehing
http://www.fmcsa.dot.gov/

national highway traffic safety administration
http://www.nhtsa.gov/NCSA

nhsta crash stats
http://www-nrd.nhtsa.dot.gov/cats/listpublications.aspx?Id=F&ShowBy=DocType

more crash stats
http://ai.fmcsa.dot.gov/CrashProfile/CrashProfileMainNew.asp

http://www.fmcsa.dot.gov/facts-research/art-stats-facts.htm

http://www-nrd.nhtsa.dot.gov/Cats/listpublications.aspx?Id=F&ShowBy=DocType

http://ai.fmcsa.dot.gov/CarrierResearchResults/CarrierResearchContent.asp

Comment: YO. if its cool, take my answer and add it to yours...i don't care about points...i want a compiled list! plz, thx!

Comment: @Albert, looks like a lot of good work.

Comment: Injury epidemiologist here. I don't see https://www.hsisinfo.org/ on this list - it's where I get the actual / individual crashes themselves, including locations. You'll need a data request. But it sounds like you want aggregate data, not individual crash records. Still, wanted to add this to the answer for future searchers.

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if my list is better (or worse), because I think it has a lot to do with Andrew's question about national/state levels. If Andrew says it's cool, I'll just have him update his answer with these links:

NCSA Publications & Data Requests
http://www-nrd.nhtsa.dot.gov/Cats/index.aspx
you probably want this guy:
http://www-nrd.nhtsa.dot.gov/Cats/listpublications.aspx?Id=F&ShowBy=DocType

Super in-depth stats
http://www-fars.nhtsa.dot.gov/Main/index.aspx

Crash stats archive
http://ai.fmcsa.dot.gov/CarrierResearchResults/Archives.asp?p=23

Stats and facts
http://www.fmcsa.dot.gov/facts-research/art-stats-facts.htm

Federal trans safety something
http://www.fmcsa.dot.gov/

National highway traffic safety administration (NHTSA)
http://www.nhtsa.gov/NCSA

NHTSA crash stats
http://www-nrd.nhtsa.dot.gov/cats/listpublications.aspx?Id=F&ShowBy=DocType

More crash stats
http://ai.fmcsa.dot.gov/CrashProfile/CrashProfileMainNew.asp

http://www.fmcsa.dot.gov/facts-research/art-stats-facts.htm

http://www-nrd.nhtsa.dot.gov/Cats/listpublications.aspx?Id=F&ShowBy=DocType

http://ai.fmcsa.dot.gov/CarrierResearchResults/CarrierResearchContent.asp

Comment: np. share and share alike. its all about openness here

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if you need something for the entire nation, but a lot of localities publish versions of this kind of data.

Two examples:
http://www.state.nj.us/transportation/refdata/accident/rawdata01-03.shtm
http://nypd.openscrape.com/#/

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Update (May 2019):
Check this new release: https://smoosavi.org/datasets/us_accidents. It contains more than 2.25 million traffic accident records which took place within the US, and will be periodically updated.

---

The following dataset is recently released and will be periodically updated: https://smoosavi.org/datasets/2019_traffic_weather_events

It covers the entire U.S, and also contains information about other types of traffic events in addition to accidents, such as congestion, construction, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want point-level data on crashes (but only for select states), I recommend submitting a data use request to the folks at the Highway Safety Information System (https://www.hsisinfo.org/) . I use that data to do small area research in NC.